# File Type of sourcecode.cpp.objcpp in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Ok so I wanted to play around with CCBlade https://github.com/hiepnd/CCBlade  and in the installation files it mentions something about changing the file type to sourcecode.ccp.objcpp and this is first time I have heard about this. here is the text :

```
"USAGE NOTICE:
- CCBlade.m, TouchTrailLayer.m and all .m file that use CCBlade or TouchTrailLayer should
have the File Type of sourcecode.cpp.objcpp (right click .m file in Xcode go to first tab and under
File Type drop down list choose the right option)"
```

could someone tell me how exactly I can do this in xcode 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select your file in project navigator.
2. Show Utilities (option + command + 0).
3. Select File Inspector (option + command + 1).
4. In File Inspector you can see File Type right under File Name.

Comment: one more question, which option represents "sourcecode.cpp.objcpp" ?? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, simply rename all .m files to .mm - that has the same effect as setting the File Type to "Objective-C++ source".